# Looking for a data visualisation library/package that can show traffic frequency through a tree of nodes in Python

Tags: python, data-visualization

[image: crude diagram of what I'm talking about]

Suppose you have a single data point that changes state, and your data describes the state changes of a number data points. Is there a library that can visualise all the states as nodes and change the thickness of the connections according to their frequency?